# assertion failed 2 different errors

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm getting two different assertion errors. For path 1, it says line 1169 vector erase iterator outside range. If I do path 2, it says line 70 vector iterator is not dereferencable. Both are assertion errors.

I am stuck at these errors, so I'm not even sure if this program would work in its intended function.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int _tmain()
{
    int adqv;
    vector<string> dvdtitle(100);
    vector<string>::iterator place;
    vector <string>::iterator del;
    string title;

    do{cout<< "welcome to your Dvd library!"
        && cout<< "     To add titles enter 1.                              To        delete titles enter 2.            Type 3 to quit"
        && cin>>adqv;

    switch (adqv)
    {case 1 : cout<<"Enter the title name"
        && cin >>title;

         break;
     case 2: 
         cout<<"enter the number of the title to be deleted.";
         cin>>*del ;

         break;
     case 3:
        {return 0;}
     default: cout<<"invalid choice";}
        dvdtitle.push_back(title);
        dvdtitle.erase(del);
        sort(dvdtitle.begin(), dvdtitle.end());
        cout<<"               These are your titles";
        for (place=dvdtitle.begin(); place!= dvdtitle.end() ; ++place);
        {cout<< *place;}
    } while (adqv !=3); 
}
```

Comment: show your "stdafx.h"

Comment: 1. A stray semicolon. Read the code carefully. 2. `del` is an invalid iterator.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you enter:

 case 1: you set title, but do nothing to set del

 case 2: you set del but do nothing to set title

Since you didn't give these initial values one of them won't be set after you leave the switch on your first loop iteration, yet you use both of them:

```
 dvdtitle.push_back(title);
 dvdtitle.erase(del);
```

The vector class can't use the initialized value in either case and is nice enough to complain instead of letting undefined behavior (or other nasty things) occur.

You need to either initialize `title` and `del` at the beginning, or you need to provide some sort of definite value to both of them inside both case 1 and 2 of your switch statement.

---

Edit:
I just noticed if you hit the default case of your switch statement neither one of them is defined, so if you opt to take care of the assigning values in your switch you'll need to add how to handle the empty case for both values in the default.  It would probably be easier to initialize them in the first place.

You might also want to reset them to whatever default state you choose at the very end or very beginning of each loop iteration.

Comment: string title;
  title="word";
 *del=100;
 do{cout<< "welcome to your Dvd library!"
 && cout<< "     To add titles enter 1.                              To delete titles enter 2.            Type 3 to quit"
  && cin>>adqv;
  
 switch (adqv)
 {case 1 : cout<<"Enter the title name"
 && cin >>title;
 
  break;
 case 2: 
 cout<<"enter the number of the title to be deleted."
 && cin>>*del ;
 
 break;
 case 3:
  {return 0;}
 default: cout<<"invalid choice";}

 
}

Comment: i tried doing that and it errors assertion at the beginning of the program now

Comment: @Lars I would recommend you initialize the del iterator to the beginning of the vector `del = dvdTitle.begin()` Secondly what new assertion is being thrown and at what line in your code (you should look through the stack trace to find the line in this code file instead of the line in the vector class file)? Also make sure you take care of that semi-colon molbdnilo pointed out.